# Runtime decimal symbol change

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

There's a problem regarding changing decimal symbol in control panel, region.
If I had a comma, then set it to dot, the application changes float data decimal separator from comma to dot as it should be. But after the next update of data comes, it changes back to a comma, even though in windows settings decimal symbol is set to be a dot.

I tried using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()` before displaying data but to no avail.

The strange thing about it is that after the first time I've changed the symbol, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.numberDecimalSeparator` property updated accordingly, but after the next set of data came, it changed back to the previous decimal symbol.

Is there a way to get decimal symbol that was updated in windows settings and set it in the application, so it won't change it back to the previous decimal?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use class `NumberFormatInfo`. Provides number formatting information and also allows you to change the format of values

More information [microsoft docs numberformatinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=net-5.0)

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
string NumberDecimalSeparator = nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator;
string PercentSymbol = nfi.PercentSymbol;
//more..................................
```

---

```
if(nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator == ".")
   nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
else
   nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";


decimal a = 0.25;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString(nfi));
```